# Passing argument from ajax post to perl not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, perl, cgi

I am trying to pass an argument to perl from ajax post, but perl just can't see it...

html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").keyup(function(){
    txt=$("input").val();
    $.post("search1.pl",{suggest:txt},function(result){
      $("span").html(result);
    }); 
  }); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
First name:
<input type="text" />
<p>Suggestions: <span></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI;
my $q = CGI->new;
my $txt = $q->param('txt');
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "txt=$txt<br>";
print "HAHA1<br>";
print "HAHA2<br>";
```

output:

Suggestions: txt=

HAHA1

HAHA2

I was expecting to see "txt=" has what I entered in the input box

Any clue ??

Comment: The name of the parameter being submitted is `suggest`, not `txt`.

Comment: Also add `use strict; use warnings;` to the top of your Perl. They will help you debug subsequent problems.

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: Quentin, pls expand on escaping as how, thanks

Comment: friedo, you mean it should be "txt:txt" ?

Comment: @CindyTurlington — https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Escape

Comment: @ikegami — The CGI script generates an HTML page: `print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";`

Comment: @ikegami — Umm, everything. The attacker could, for instance, give the victim a link `http://example.com/search1.pl?txt=<script>and_now_I_steal_your_cookies()</script>`.

Comment: @ikegami — No. The **attacker** gives the victim that link, then the **attacker steals the cookies** (because `and_now_I_steal_your_cookies()` reads the cookies using JS, then constructs a URL to **the attacker's server** which includes the cookie data in a query string (for instance), and then requests it (via XHR, or setting `location` or whatever).

Comment: @Quentin, I see. Sounds like the solution is to change the text/html Content-Type to text/plain.

Answer (score 3):

You have called your parameter `suggest`

```
$.post("search1.pl",{suggest:txt}
```

but you are trying to read one called `txt`.

Change to:

```
my $txt = $q->param('suggest');
```

Comment: what is the exact meaning of suggest:txt, it means suggest is a text field ?

Comment: No, it means "Send the server a parameter called `suggest` with the value of the variable `txt`".